# ARKit template project is not displaying SpriteKit nodes

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, ios11, arkit

I'm trying to learn the basics of `ARKit` and I created a project in `XCode 9 beta 4` by using the template for an AR app with `SpriteKit`. This project is supposed to already have the implementation of a sample app that displays an emoji in an `SKLabelNode` when you touch the screen.

I'm trying to run this sample in an iPad Mini 4 running `iOS 11`. I had to remove the `arkit` key from the `Info.plist`, and then the app runs. But the emojis are not shown. I also tried [example](https://github.com/eh3rrera/ARKitGameSpriteKit) of `ARKit` with `SpriteKit`, and the images are not displayed.

However, I could successfully run [Apple's sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/) which renders 3D models and I can see them. And also [this other example](https://github.com/hanleyweng/CoreML-in-ARKit) that uses `SceneKit` as well.

How is it possible that I'm able to display 3D `SceneKit` objects but not 2D `SpriteKit` objects in my device? What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad mini 4 is not supported. ARKit requires an A9 or better processor

The devices that use A9 or A10 chips are:

> iPhone 6s and 6s Plus
>   iPhone 7 and 7 Plus
>   iPhone SE
>   iPad Pro (9.7, 10.5 or 12.9)
>   iPad (2017)

source:http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-11-arkit-compatibility-check-if-your-device-is-compatible-with-apples-new-ar-platform/

Comment: What I don't understand is why then I'm able to run the SceneKit examples, a 3D model is supposed to be heavier than a 2D SpriteKit one... it is not possible to run ARKit + SpriteKit at all with no A9 processor? Even in a "limited" way?

Comment: You cant run any of the examples, what you are doing is hacking it to just run SceneKit, you are not implementing the ARKit features.

Comment: I didn't change any code. When running the Apple's sample from Xcode in debug mode I get a crash, but when I run it without linking to Xcode I see things. The same with the other SceneKit example. It goes very slow, but I get the 3D labels rendered.

Comment: Yes, you are rendering the SceneKit parts of the app,  the ARKit parts will not work.  Remember, this is a beta, so things will be passable when they shouldn't be